# System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration.get_ServiceResolver() not found

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api

i've updated to the new mvc 4 RC version released this week and after deployment to azure, i got the error message:

> Method not found: 'System.Web.Http.Services.DependencyResolver System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration.get_ServiceResolver()'.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> > Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Web.Http.Services.DependencyResolver System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration.get_ServiceResolver()'.

I'm using the GlobalConfiguration.Configuration object to configure all the stuff and everything works on my machine.

Could you help me with this please?

Thanks!

Comment: I've found the solution:
My Buildserver hasn't installed the latest MVC4 RC and because of that, the AzuerPackage was build with the old MVC4 Beta Dlls.